# save git hash in the same file without changing the current hash code

Tags: git, github, hash, version-control, hook

I am trying to code up a version control schema based library system.
So as a part of the functionality i am trying record the current hash of a file and insert it as a part of the history and save it but not to change the current version!!!! because when i save the file , the hash code immediately changes which is not what i wanted Pls help me in this !!! Thanks in advance 
 I tried the `git rev-parse HEAD 1.txt` but still the problem persists !!!!
Attaching the screenshot for your perusal 
[image]

Here in the screenshot when git hash-object 1.txt i am getting `"79f3721a53ea877e2cc89e6655f1922ed8f01e23"` but in the file above the old hash code has got piped !!!!

Pls help on this !!!!!!!

Comment: Short version: it can't be done, it's like asking for the sum of a list of (nonzero) numbers including the sum of the numbers appended to the end of the list of numbers.  You start with 1, 2, 3 and the sum is 6, so you need 6 + 6 which is 12, so you need 12 + 12 which is 24, and so on.

Comment: hmmm thank you!!!! Just thought it could be possible, because there is a way to store the commit hash prior to the commit !!!!!

Comment: @SritharanM, maybe gitattributes `clean` and `smudge` can be of any help, depending on what you need (see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)

Comment: You can store the hash of a file (or indeed of any git object) *somewhere else*, so that "the hash of the final object" is not part of the object being hashed.  This is how git works: files get hashed; those hashes, plus name-and-mode, are used to make "tree" objects, which get hashed; those hashes are stored in commit objects, which get hashed; and the commit hashes are stored in references (branch names and the like).  In each case the hash is stored outside the object-that-is-being-hashed.

Comment: yeah Torek, thanks for the valuable inputs, after you mentioned about the impossibility I thought of designing the feature set like that .I am going to maintain the entire blob data in a separate file for revisioning entity. Once again thanks for giving the entire structural flow of the git hash flow. This idea will be useful for my future design purpose. Have a great day.

Comment: HI jordan, I also looked  at the git attribute but that didnt help me in what i was expecting. these stuffs happen at the time of commit, but what i was expecting is much earlier. I needed to do the hash piping without changing the hash of the file which was impossible